# Windows Virtual Machine getting connection refused to port 9090 webpack dev server

Tags: javascript, virtualbox, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a Meteor + Webpack application I'm working on, but I can't get a Windows VM (Win10, IE11, from modern.ie running inside VirtualBox) to access the Webpack dev server assets on port 9090, while the Meteor assets on the same host but on port 3000 work fine for whatever reason. The app is running and being accessed at {host}:3000 but this one bundled JS file is on on the same host at port 9090 and the VM is unable to fetch it.

Comment: Did you try setting `host` to `0.0.0.0`? I think it defaults to `localhost`. That can cause issues with virtual machines.

Comment: @bebraw That's what it originally was. The external asset was being linked in the HTML at `0.0.0.0:9090/path/to/script.js`. I believe a guest machine treats `0.0.0.0` as its own localhost and doesn't see outside. Either way, that's where my woes started.

Comment: Can you try a lower port that 9090? I.e., 4000 or some such. You could also try running Meteor through 9090 and Webpack through 3000. Maybe it's something VirtualBox related.

Comment: Tried post 7070 and post 2000. No luck. Looking at the Network panel, it looks like IE is never even attempting to fetch the script. When I try to directly load the script URL, IE11 says it "Can't reach this page"

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my.domain.dev:2000/assets/client.bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Really weird. Do other browsers work any better?